# How to properly write a custom user model and manager in Django v3?

Tags: django

I have a user model like below

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Type:
        FP = 'fp'
        BRANCH = 'branch'
        CHOICES = (
            (FP, '채용공고 보기'),
            (BRANCH, '채용공고 내기'),
        )

    class Sex:
        MALE = 'male'
        FEMALE = 'female'
        CHOICES = (
            (MALE, '남성'),
            (FEMALE, '여성')
        )

    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        verbose_name='계정 종류',
        choices=Type.CHOICES,
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='이메일',
        unique=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        verbose_name='이름'
    )
    nickname = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        verbose_name='닉네임',
        unique=True,
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        verbose_name='전화번호',
    )
    sex = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        verbose_name='성별',
        choices=Sex.CHOICES,
    )
    company_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='회사이름',
        max_length=256,
    )
    dob = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='생년월일'
    )
    profile_img = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name='프로필 이미지',
        upload_to=user_profile_img_file_path,
    )
    sns_id = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='SNS ID'
    )
    sns_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='SNS 종류',
        max_length=20,
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

and custom manager like below

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        sys.stderr.write(repr(extra_fields))

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('이메일은 필수사항입니다')
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
```

and test looking like below

```
    def test_create_valid_user_success(self):
        """
        Test that creating user with valid payload is successful
        """
        profile_img = self.generate_photo_file()

        payload = {
            'email': 'test@gmail.com',
            'password': '1234567',
            'type': 'fp',
            'name': 'testname',
            'nickname': 'testnickname',
            'phone': '01012341234',
            'sex': 'male',
            'company_name': 'company_name',
            'dob': '1992-11-23T10:22:38+0000',
            'profile_img': profile_img,
            'sns_id': '1234567',
            'sns_type': 'facebook',
        }

        res = self.client.post(CREATE_USER_URL, payload)
        sys.stderr.write(repr(res))

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(**res.data)
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password(payload['password']))
        self.assertNotIn('password', res.data)
```

unfortunately I am keep getting below error when I run the above test

```
 Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.
```

I am not much of a django expert; however, as far as I know what I am doing above is pretty standard and I do not have any relationship in the user model.

Even stranger behaviour is that if I directly create the user with the same payload without using the APIClient, it works flawlessly. What's wrong with the test I have?

Answer (score 0):

It's not normally recommend to write a custom user model and manager unless you really need it. If you are just looking to extend the user model then you would normally approach that by creating another model with a OneToOne relationship to the User model.

This is outlines within the official documents - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model